# Seagate expansion external HD settings all files to executable

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I just bought a Seagate Expansion USB harddrive to make some backups and I noticed something very strange happening. To every file/dir that I put there when I recover it in my linux I noticed that it has the permissions set to `777`. Giving that both process of recording the data and later restoring it happens in a linux machine and the usb hd is using NTFS, does anyone knows why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTFS doesn't support POSIX permissions; the permissions are set on mount for the entire filesystem. Use the `umask`, `fmask`, and `dmask` mount option or create a usermap file and use ACLs if you need different permissions to be used. See the `mount.ntfs-3g(8)` man page for details.